# How to install windows after ubuntu?

Tags: windows

i had a windows on my pc, and installed ubuntu (completely, no windows anymore), and there is so many apps i need which are not linux supported and doesn't good option in virtualbox. I looked for answer on internet but never finded exactly what i need for. I tryed extended partitions, mount options /windows and /boot but none of that works. So how to install windows 7 again? Only windows 7, no ubuntu, no any linux. Thanks. And please explain it to me in steps. Like i am stupid, because i am for this things.

Comment: Do you have Windows 7 installation media and product key?

Comment: You know what,  if I were you, I'd just start all over again.  Wipe the hard drive, install and configure Windows first, *then* install Ubuntu using the "alongside Windows " option.  This is the easy way.  The other way round is a real b***h if you're a newbie.

Comment: I have cd with my windows which is bootable and i have product key. How to wipe hard drive? Oh, and i don't want ubuntu anymore. Only windows.

Comment: Well, i did something, but now my bootmgr is missing. And there is nothing i can do, because now i don't have any os. And still cannot install windows.

Comment: "cannot install Windows"  Why not?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: My pc won't boot my cd with windows, only ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to simply zero out the first part of your hard drive and start again.  (Zeroing out the first part of your drive will make Windows think its totally blank)

You can do this using a Linux boot disk with a command like "dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=1024 count=1024" where sdX is your hard drive - normally, but not always /dev/sda

You can probably run this command from your running Ubuntu setup and then reboot your system (ie pull out the power cable).

Once you have done that, simply install Windows from CD following the prompts.